# Migration notice disappears when refreshing edited post

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration-notice

I think I just observed a glitch which I'm unable to reproduce.

I was watching [Using Small RAID5's to prevent data loss](https://superuser.com/questions/768326/using-small-raid5s-to-prevent-data-loss) and the answer was edited. When I clicked the notification to reload the answer, the migration notice disappeared.

Comment: I've seen that too, IIRC after a migrated question was edited.